# Deleting a particular element from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

```
state = { filters: ['all'] }


this.state.filters.includes('humans') ? 
    this.state.filters.filter(val => val !== 'humans') : this.state.filters.push(dropdown)
```

I'm using a condition such that, when I click on a button the item('humans') gets pushed to state and when I click on the same button again I need to remove the item('humans') from the array. Push is working fine, I need help in removing it. I used filter like the above code , it does not get added again to the array but also not removing.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
let index = this.state.filters.indexOf('humans');
if (index !== -1)
   this.state.filters.splice(index, 1);
```

Or you better follow this approach to [avoid mutating the state](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/) in React:

```
let array = [...this.state.filters]; // make a separate copy of the array
let index = array.indexOf('humans')
if (index === -1) { // not in the array
   array.push('humans');
   this.setState({filters: array});
} else { // exists in the array
   array.splice(index, 1);
   this.setState({filters: array});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove an element from array, You can do below thing

```
filters.splice(index_of_the_val, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't modify the state with the push, 'cause it might not trigger the re-rendering. You should use the `setState` method.

```
toggleFilter = filter => {
  const isIncluded = this.state.filters.includes(filter)

  const add = (filters, filter) =>
    filters.concat(filter)

  const remove = (filters, filter) =>
    filters.filter(f => f !== filter)

  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    filters: isIncluded 
               ? remove(prevState.filters, filter)
               : add(prevState.filters, filter)
  }))
}
```